# Jenkins only builds git project with two branch specifiers

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I'm having trouble creating a Jenkins Job to build a specific branch.

For some reason, it only works if I specify more than 1 branch specifier.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug I should report?

## Build Examples

### Successful Build

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@3.0.0">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git</url>
        <credentialsId>GitLab_SSH</credentialsId>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>*/master</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>*/master</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <extensions/>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

#### Console Log:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitGud_DMZ
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH Key for GitLabs
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/dmz
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Checking out Revision ccf563e57ccff42045d442e4a4f4354c62401cd7 (origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f ccf563e57ccff42045d442e4a4f4354c62401cd7
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

### Failed Build

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@3.0.0">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git</url>
        <credentialsId>GitLab_SSH</credentialsId>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>*/master</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <extensions/>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

#### Console Log

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitGud_DMZ
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitGud_DMZ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH Key for GitLabs
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH Key for GitLabs
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags git@gitlab.mkmeier.com:msn/gitgud.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```